# Woocommerce - how can i add items to cart using onclick - multiple items at once with custom prices

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, json

I am actually creating an order form (sort of). Based on the items a customer selects, logic needs to be applied to **calculate the custom price per item**. Custom price is now stored in **hidden input fields**.

What is the **best practice to implement** this? Eventually i would like to add all items and their custom prices added to the cart.

I am currently testing with **a php function** in combination with **action **woocommerce_before_calculate_totals****.

global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(64,1,154, array(),array('add_length' => array('Option'=>'test'),'custom_price' =>1200.50));

As a standalone function it works. But integrating it to the page, i am not sure.

My questions;

- How can i call this function from a button onclick event? The php function is stored in the function.php file
- The custom price is calculated using a php function and stored in a hidden input field. Don't think this is the most secure way to do it. What is a better solution?
- Preferable i have a function that i can use to enter product_id, qty and custom price. Add it to the onclick button. Everything in a secure way.